# UIView transistionWithAnimation not working

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimationtransition

So I wanted to learn transition animations with blocks. So I went to the apple documentation and took an example of animation using the [old method (without blocks)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009222). I have taken the code snippet (slight modification) and tested this. It works perfectly

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:nil];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:kTransitionDuration];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight
                                forView:self.view
                                cache:YES];

if ([self.instructionsView superview]) {
    [self.instructionsView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:contentView];
} else {
    [self.contentView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:instructionsView];
}

[UIView commitAnimations];

// adjust our done/info buttons accordingly
if ([instructionsView superview]) {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
} else {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = flipButton;
}
```

Now the below code is my attempt to convert the code on top to a code with blocks

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:kTransitionDuration options:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{
        if ([self.instructionsView superview]) {
            [self.instructionsView removeFromSuperview];
            [self.view addSubview:contentView];
        } else {
            [self.contentView removeFromSuperview];
            [self.view addSubview:instructionsView];
        }
} completion:^(BOOL finished){

        if ([instructionsView superview]) {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
        } else {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = flipButton;
        }
}];
```

From what I can understand is that the code below should work. I am testing this on iOS 4.2 which supports blocks. However it does not seem to animate and I don't understand why that is. It changes the views, just doesn't animate. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting transitionWithView  with transitionToView:fromView